# Javascript to redirect to a page and dynamically modify it

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying:

1. I am clicking on a button Proceed that takes me to another html page.
2. Then I am creating a dynamic table based on my array.

But page doesn't display the table.
Note: I want to achieve this via JS only not Jquery or any other framework.

Code:

Below function gets called when I press the Proceed button

```
function Proceed(){

    window.location.href = '\cart.html';

    function addItems(){

        var cartTable = document.createElement("table");

        var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");

        tr1.appendChild(createElement("td"));
        tr1.appendChild(createElement("td"));
        tr1.appendChild(createElement("td"));

        tr1.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode('Sr. Number'));
        tr1.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode('Item'));
        tr1.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode('Price'));

        cartTable.appendChild(tr1);

        for(i=0; i<cartCount; i++){

            var cartItem = myCart[i];

            var tr = document.createElement("tr");

            tr.appendChild(createElement("td"));
            tr.appendChild(createElement("td"));
            tr.appendChild(createElement("td"));

            tr.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode(i+1));
            tr.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode(cartItem.Name));
            tr.cells[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode(cartItem.Price));

            cartTable.appendChild(tr);

        }

        document.getElementByID(finalCart).innerHTML = cartTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how stuff works. Once you change the page, the browser takes over and no more JS code that is on your current page gets executed.

Comment: You'd need the JS on the page you're *going* to, not on the page you're navigating away from. Because you're navigating away from that page.

Comment: If you really need to navigate to another page and persist the data, you could store it in a cookie for the next page's javascript to read it from.

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate away from a page and then continue to run scripts on the page you just left.

Instead, you can generate the new page's html first, then convert it to a dataURI you can redirect or link to.  (Since this is inside an SO snippet I can't target a new window or redirect to it automatically, so I'm just generating a direct link; in real life you wouldn't have that restriction.)

```js
function Proceed() {

  /* since this is all going to be converted to a string anyway,
  it would be easier to just create the html as a string instead
  of using DOM methods. In the interest of not mucking around too 
  much with your existing code I'm leaving that as is and then 
  extracting the html string with .outerHTML. */

  var cartTable = document.createElement("table");
  var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
  tr1.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  tr1.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  tr1.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  tr1.cells[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode('Sr. Number'));
  tr1.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item'));
  tr1.cells[2].appendChild(document.createTextNode('Price'));

  cartTable.appendChild(tr1);
  /* Etcetera for remainder of table */

  // create the data URI:
  var generatedLink = "data:text/html;base64," + window.btoa(cartTable.outerHTML);

  // create a link to it:
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<a href='" + generatedLink + "'>Go to generated page</a>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Proceed()">Generate Link</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

(It may go without saying that you're probably better off generating this serverside as a normal HTML page, but if you *need* to stay clientside, this should work.)

Comment: thanks Daniel and all others. I'll make the changes :)